# maven dependency in build.xml file is not able to download

Tags: maven, build, ant

Added the maven jar dependency in build.xml with bellow target.

```
<artifact:dependencies pathId="dependency.classpath">
     <dependency groupId="org.glassfish.metro" artifactId="webservices-rt" version="2.4.3"/>
</artifact:dependencies>
```

During Build getting below error

```
    [artifact:dependencies] 1) org.glassfish.metro:webservices-rt:jar:2.4.3
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies]   Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies]   Then, install it using the command: 
[artifact:dependencies]       mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.glassfish.metro -DartifactId=webservices-rt -Dversion=2.4.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies]   Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
[artifact:dependencies]       mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.glassfish.metro -DartifactId=webservices-rt -Dversion=2.4.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies]   Path to dependency: 
[artifact:dependencies]     1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0
[artifact:dependencies]     2) org.glassfish.metro:webservices-rt:jar:2.4.3
```

Comment: What exactly do you use to build all these? Is this a Maven extension for Ant?

Answer (score 0):

The `maven-ant-tasks` plugin has been abandoned for several years. Note the big red message near the top of the page: https://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/

It's failing now because Maven Central recently switched to HTTPS, so the default repository URL that `maven-ant-tasks` tries to use returns a 401 error. Apache suggests using `resolver-ant-tasks` now https://maven.apache.org/resolver-ant-tasks/

You could also use Apache Ivy, or simply use Ant's `<exec>` task to run the `mvn` executable just as you would in the command line.